# Changes to fringe-indicator-alist not taking effect

Tags: fringe

It seems like the variable [`fringe-indicator-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Fringe-Indicators.html) can be modified to hide the line-wrap indicators on the edges / fringe of the window.

I am having trouble getting this to work properly in the GUI of emacs on MacOS.

I added the following to my `init.el`, but the changes are not having an effect. Is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to update the values?

Specifically, I want to change `continuation` to `nil nil`.

```
(setq fringe-indicator-alist '((truncation nil nil)
    (continuation nil nil)
    (overlay-arrow . right-triangle)
    (up . up-arrow)
    (down . down-arrow)
    (top top-left-angle top-right-angle)
    (bottom bottom-left-angle bottom-right-angle top-right-angle top-left-angle)
    (top-bottom left-bracket right-bracket top-right-angle top-left-angle)
    (empty-line . empty-line)
    (unknown . question-mark)))
```

Comment: Are you using Emacs in the Terminal, or the GUI version of Emacs?  Emacs in the Terminal does not use fringes.

Comment: @lawlist I'm using the GUI version (updated in post).

Comment: **TEST**:  *No `.emacs`.  Open a GUI version of Emacs, in this case 27.2-3 downloaded from https://emacsformacosx.com/ .  The default buffer that is visible is `*GNU Emacs*`.  The line "GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, NS appkit-1404.47 Version 10.11.6 (Build 15G22010))" is wrapped.  I evaluate `(setq truncate-lines t)` and the aforementioned line of text is now continued beyond the length of the screen, and there is a right-arrow visible in the fringe.  Then, I evaluate the code posted by the O.P. in the question above, and the right-arrow (continuation) disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fringe-indicator-alist` is a *buffer-local* variable, which means that the code the O.P. wishes to use should either be evaluated in every buffer desired, or set the default value by using `setq-default`.

```
`fringe-indicator-alist' is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is shown below.

  Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.
  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 22.1.
```

Comment: Thanks — updating `setq` to `setq-default` in `init.el` did the trick.